# How to use integrate.quad with an array

Tags: python, function, scipy, numerical-integration

I would like to use integrate.quad with an array but it returns me : *"TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"*

I understand that the first argument which is required must be a scalar. But the argument I want to use comes from a function that depends on one parameter and that return an array and I can't get the problem fixed:

Here is my script in Python:

```
from scipy import integrate as intg

DfH_ref_jp = np.array([0,-393.52,-110.53,-74.87,-241.83,0]) *1000
n_jp = np.array([1.2,0.2,0.15,0.001,0.49,0.30])
Tref = 1298
Ta = 1310

def c_jp(T):
    t = T/1000
    XC = np.array([1,t,t**2,t**3,t**(-2)])
    Mah = M_ah(T)                            # a matrix defined before
    c = np.dot(Mah[:,:5],XC)

    return c

H1_jp = n_jp * (DfH_ref_jp + intg.quad(c_jp,Tref,Ta)[0])   # this where it doesn't work / [0] because intg.quad returns an array and I want the first value
```

So I have tried with a function which returns a scalar:

```
def c_jp0(T):
    t = T/1000
    XC = np.array([1,t,t**2,t**3,t**(-2)])
    Mah = M_ah(T)
    c = np.dot(Mah[0,:5],XC)

    return c

H1_jp = np.zeros(6, dtype=float)
H1_jp[0] = n_jp[0] * (DfH_ref_jp[0] + intg.quad(c_jp0,Tref,Ta)[0])
```

It works but I don't want to specify 6 functions : c_jp0 ... c_jp6.
Does anyone has an idea how to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: In order to give you a solution for your case you have give all the variables we need to run your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `quad_vec`:  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad_vec.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

The [quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) method, is designed to integrate a scalar function only over one scalar variable.

If your integral has only one integration variable, but depends on other parameters you can pass them via params in `quad(func, a, b, params)`.

If you want to integrate over multiple variables you can use [nquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html#scipy.integrate.nquad), in that case you have to give a limit for each of your variables.

If the limits are constant you can pass them directly, if the limits depend on other integration variable you must pass the limits as a function of variables
that are not integrated yet.

e.g.
For instance, to calculate the volume of a cube having one corner at the origin and other corner at the point (1,1,1).

```
from scipy import integrate as intg
nquad(lambda x,y,z: 1.0, [(0,1), (0,1), (0,1)])
```

Or the volume of square base pyramid with vertices at (0,0,1), (-1,-1,0) and (1,1,0). Where the limits of `x` and `y` depends on `z`

```
from scipy import integrate as intg
intg.nquad(lambda x,y,z: 1.0, [lambda y,z: (z-1,1-z), lambda z: (z-1,1-z), (0,1)])
```

Comment: It wasn't what I needed but thank you for this very clear explanation, that I might need in the future.